# Can I return to stranger missions?

Tags: red-dead-redemption-2

While making my way around the horseshoe overlook, I found [Máximo Cristóbal Valdespino](https://reddead.fandom.com/wiki/M%C3%A1ximo_Crist%C3%B3bal_Valdespino). He offered to give me a treasure map for $10. However, at the time I had just paid a bounty off and only had $6 to my name, so I walked away.

Now that I can afford the map, I can't find him! Have I missed out on this mission? Or will I be able to re-find Máximo Cristóbal Valdespino and retry?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [this guide](http://www.powerpyx.com/red-dead-redemption-2-all-that-glitters-stranger-mission-walkthrough/), if you are unable to find Máximo, you likely missed your window of obtaining the treasure map from him. Fortuntely, you can still obtain the treasure map by purchasing it from any one of the [fences](http://www.powerpyx.com/red-dead-redemption-2-fence-vendor-locations/)

> In case you scared him away, robbed or killed him by accident, you can buy his map from any fence in the game.

For what it's worth, declining the offer rather than walking away would have brought the price down to $5

Comment: Just coming back to this to confirm that it did work! The fence at Emerald Ranch was selling it later on. Thanks again.

Comment: @KarlNicoll Glad I could help!